# Reducing latency in read operations

Tags: mysql, performance, aws-aurora, query-performance

Table size 45 million rows
Schema: item name, categories and subcategories, order quantity and price.

What is the fastest way to put each item into an appropriate bucket?

For example: price range given will be: 500- 600
We have 10 buckets: 500-510, 510-520, ...590-600
We also have filters on particular category and subcategory, i.e. specific category and subcategory have to be only considered in a query.

By bucketing, it means that all items which falls in a said range, and belongs to the particular category and subcategory, there order quantity will be summed.

What will be an optimal way to construct the query? We have a query which does all the processing in one go using `case` and `when`. However, this takes around 18 sec or more mostly.

This has to be optimized. I have tried adding indexes, which is not helping much.

Comment: Show the query, show the `EXPLAIN {query}`, show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tbl}`. How much of the table will a given price range cover?

Answer (score 0):

I would compute the buckets by `FLOOR(price/10)`.  Should `510` be in the `50` bucket?  Or the `51` bucket?  Or both?

"put each item into an appropriate bucket" sounds like an `INSERT` statement.  But 
"will be summed" sounds like a `SELECT` statement.  Which do you mean?

Assuming you are selecting all 45M rows, here is the optimal query:

```
SELECT  10 * FLOOR(price/10) AS 'price bucket',
        category,
        subcategory,
        SUM(order_quantity) AS 'quantity'
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

(Or do you need `item` in the `GROUP BY`?)

The real performance problem is that you need to read all 45M rows.

There might be a way to speed it up.  What is the data flow?  Do you insert rows and then never change or delete them?  If so a Summary Table that you build and maintain (daily?) would be much smaller and faster.